# hidden copy in STL vector?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, copy

I am experiencing unexpected performance degradation when using vectors with classes.

I have a csv_File class that reads in a csv file and stores the contents in a 2D vector. There's a member function that allows access, e.g.

```
    csv_File file("file.csv");
    file.access(2,2);
```

To access the 2,2 element.

Then, I have another class csv_Array that stores multiple csv_File objects in a vector, e.g private member vector
There's a member function that allows access, i.e. it returns a csv_File object, for example:

```
    csv_Array file_array(5); //store 5 csv_File objects
    file_array.grab(0).access(2,2);
```

In the second line, grab returns a csv_File object (in this case, the first one) and access is a member function of the csv_File object.

However, I have noticed that the call
csv_Array.grab(0).access(2,2); 
is much slower than it should be (it should be just 3 vector::at calls).

Is there some sort of hidden copy going on that is making this very slow?

EDIT: Here are some of the relevant function prototypes:

```
    //Access in csv_File
    std::string access(int row, int column);

    //grab in csv_Array and csv_Analysis (mentioned below)
    csv_File grab(int index);
```

ADDITIONAL DETAILS (if necessary):
The application of this code is to load a bunch of csv files into memory before passing it to a friend class that will do some calculations with the data. Schematically, I have the following:

1) csv_Array has private member vector storage;
2) csv_Analysis is a class that is a friend of csv_Array
3) csv_Analysis accesses vector storage, which is in csv_Array
4) This access is done by passing csv_Analysis a reference to storage in csv_Array (so no copy hopefully....), e.g 
 public:
  csv_Analysis(csv_Array &csv_block);

Thus, the call given above[file_array.grab(0).access(2,2); ]
 actually has one additional class "level" in between and is more like

```
    csv_Analysis analysis_Object(file_array); 
    analysis_Object.grab(0).access(2,2);
```

where grab acts in the same way, and is also defined as a member function of csv_Analysis class.

Comment: Can you post the prototype of your grab and access functions ?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the prototypes, I can see now why this might be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to make `grab` return a reference rather than a copy:

```
csv_File& grab(int index);
```

Comment: Yes, by if you don't do this grab will copy everything inside csv_File, including your vector. If you come from Java or C# worlds, you need to keep in mind that C++ use values most of the time and values are copied with their content.

Comment: Ah yes, I believe this will fix the error. It's also important to note that the returned reference needs to be declared a const or the code won't compile.  Actually, there are some other compilation issues so it doesn't look like it will be so straightforward to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if you showed precisely how the functions are declared, especially the return values. I suspect you're returning a copy instead of a reference, but I can't tell yet.

Comment: I have now added the information to my original post, thanks for looking.